# Как запушит в массив letters первый символ каждого слова?

Tags: javascript

```
function firstTask(){
    var letters = [];
    var row = 'Crazy Amazing Native Awesome Daily Adorible';
    var newRow = row.split(' ');

}
firstTask();
```

Comment: `var letters = row.split(' ').map(w => w[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var letters = [];
var row = 'Crazy Amazing Native Awesome Daily Adorible';
var newRow = row.split(' ');
newRow.forEach(e => {
  letters.push(e[0]);
});

console.log(letters);
```